# Plotting bug with pandas 0.21

Tags: python, pandas

On running the following code:
    plt.fill_between(df.index.unique(), min_vals, max_vals)

I get the error:

```
*** TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

`df.index.unique()` is

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-01', '2005-01-02', '2005-01-03', '2005-01-04',
               '2005-01-05', '2005-01-06', '2005-01-07', '2005-01-08',
               '2005-01-09', '2005-01-10',
               ...
               '2005-07-05', '2005-07-06', '2005-07-07', '2005-07-08',
               '2005-07-09', '2005-07-10', '2005-07-11', '2005-07-12',
               '2005-07-13', '2005-07-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', length=195, freq=None)
```

and `min_vals` and `max_vals` are numpy arrays of same length as `df.index.unique()`. Sample:

```
array([ 118.15219205,  118.09140844,  118.05368241,  118.01825058,
        117.9923672 ,  117.97512   ,  117.98164725,  117.96102018,
        117.93014226,  117.89721839])
```

I do not get this error with pandas version 0.20.3 but I do get this error with pandas version 0.21. How to fix this?

Comment: maybe related to this: https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#pd-unique-will-now-be-consistent-with-extension-types

Comment: If you think there is a bug, why post it on StackOverflow instead of the [pandas issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)?

Comment: good point @SethMMorton, I am not sure if it is a bug or just behavior that is changed and I need to adapt code

Comment: Looks like a bug that has roots in numpy: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/343, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5610.